# How to conditionally assign to a variable in functional way?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I need to assign a value to a variable based on condition. I want to do it with a functional programming paradigm in mind, thus I cannot declare it in outer scope and then reassign.

```
// let foo = undefined // no-let!
if(condition) {
  const foo = 1
} else {
  const foo = 0
}
do_some_stuff(foo) // Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined
```

I know, I can use ternary expression here like
`const foo = condition ? 1 : 0`
but what if I have some other routine to do inside my condition, like:

```
if(condition) {
  const foo = 1
  do_stuff()
} else {
  const foo = 0
  do_other_stuff()
}
do_third_stuff(foo)
```

Comment: What about function composition if you desire a functional style?

Comment: provide an example plz

Comment: You are still stuck in imperative thinking. Your functions neither receive nor return a value. They are completely useless. Functional programming is not just about using functions, but using them in a pure way. A pure function takes a value and returns a transformed value. Nothing else. Next you will recognize that you can compose such pure functions, which dramatically reduces the need for intermediate values assigned to variables.

Comment: What is `do_stuff` and `do_other_stuff` supposed to provide? It doesn't return a value you use so it's either side effects or dead code. If it's side effects then it doesn't help changing a `let` to `const`

Comment: @reify should be thinking in a solution like my recently added answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is stopping you from splitting the two:

```
const foo = condition ? 1 : 0;

if(condition) {
    do_stuff();
} else {
    do_other_stuff();
}

do_third_stuff(foo);
```

In case `condition` is an expensive execution, simply assign it to a variable before using it multiple times:

```
let isFoo =  expensiveIsFooMethod();

const foo = isFoo ? 1 : 0;

if(isFoo) {
    do_stuff();
} else {
    do_other_stuff();
}

do_third_stuff(foo);
```

You're right that it would be cleaner if you didn't have to repeat the condition, but you've introduced this limitation because you're using a `const` variable which makes it impossible to assign a value to your `const` in more than one place.

I suggest outweighing the two options here. What matters to you more: cleaner syntax, or ensuring you'll never overwrite the value?

Comment: See @reify's comment on the question

Answer (score 3):

Probably you would encode your case using some *algebraic data type* (ADT) like `Either`. That is, you may cover two subcases: *left* and *right*.

See the code from `// --> Solution starts here` onwards. Previous code is a mini standard FP library using vanilla JavaScript to make the code runnable. Check it and enjoy!

```js
// Mini standard library
// -------------------------------

// The identity combinator
// I :: a -> a
const I = x => x

// Either ADT
const Either = (() => {
   // Creates an instance of Either.Right
   //
   // of :: b -> Either a b
   const of = x => ({ right: x })
   
   // Creates an instance of Either.Right
   //
   // Right :: b -> Either a b
   const Right = of
   
   // Creates an instance of Either.Left
   //
   // Left :: a -> Either a b
   const Left = x => ({ left: x })
   
   // Maps Either.Left or Either.Right in a single operation
   //
   // bimap :: (a -> c) -> (b -> d) -> Either a b -> Either c -> d
   const bimap = f => g => ({ left, right }) => left ? Left (f (left)) : Right (g (right))
   
   // Lifts a value to Either based on a condition, where false 
   // results in Left, and true is Right.
   //
   // tagBy :: (a -> Boolean) -> a -> Either a a
   const tagBy = f => x => f (x) ? Right (x) : Left (x)
   
   // Unwraps Either.Left or Either.Right with mapping functions
   //
   // either :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Either a b -> c
   const either = f => g => ({ left, right }) => left ? f (left) : g (right)
   
   // Unwraps Either.Left or Either.Right and outputs the raw value on them
   //
   // unwrap :: Either a b -> c
   const unwrap = either (I) (I)
   
   return { of, Right, Left, bimap, tagBy, either, unwrap }
}) ()

// --> Solution starts here

// Lifts to Either.Right if x is greater than 3, 
// otherwise, x is encoded as Left.
//
// tagGt3 :: Number -> Either Number Number
const tagGt3 = Either.tagBy (x => x > 3)

// doStuff :: Number -> Number
const doStuff = x => x + 1

// doStuff2 :: Number -> Number
const doStuff2 = x => x * 4

// doStuff3 :: Either Number Number -> Either Number Number
const doStuff3 = Either.bimap (doStuff) (doStuff2) // <-- here's the decision!

const eitherValue1 = doStuff3 (tagGt3 (2))
const eitherValue2 = doStuff3 (tagGt3 (30))


const output1 = Either.unwrap (eitherValue1)
const output2 = Either.unwrap (eitherValue2)

console.log ('output1: ', output1)
console.log ('output2: ', output2)
```

### Refactor using pipes

Now I introduce `pipe` to glue a composition of one or more unary functions, which makes the code more elegant:

```js
// Mini standard library
// -------------------------------

// The identity combinator
// I :: a -> a
const I = x => x

// Pipes many unary functions
//
// pipe :: [a -> b] -> a -> c
const pipe = xs => x => xs.reduce ((o, f) => f (o), x)

// Either ADT
const Either = (() => {
   // Creates an instance of Either.Right
   //
   // of :: b -> Either a b
   const of = x => ({ right: x })
   
   // Creates an instance of Either.Right
   //
   // Right :: b -> Either a b
   const Right = of
   
   // Creates an instance of Either.Left
   //
   // Left :: a -> Either a b
   const Left = x => ({ left: x })
   
   // Maps Either.Left or Either.Right in a single operation
   //
   // bimap :: (a -> c) -> (b -> d) -> Either a b -> Either c -> d
   const bimap = f => g => ({ left, right }) => left ? Left (f (left)) : Right (g (right))
   
   // Lifts a value to Either based on a condition, where false 
   // results in Left, and true is Right.
   //
   // tagBy :: (a -> Boolean) -> a -> Either a a
   const tagBy = f => x => f (x) ? Right (x) : Left (x)
   
   // Unwraps Either.Left or Either.Right with mapping functions
   //
   // either :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Either a b -> c
   const either = f => g => ({ left, right }) => left ? f (left) : g (right)
   
   // Unwraps Either.Left or Either.Right and outputs the raw value on them
   //
   // unwrap :: Either a b -> c
   const unwrap = either (I) (I)
   
   return { of, Right, Left, bimap, tagBy, either, unwrap }
}) ()

// --> Solution starts here

// doStuff :: Number -> Number
const doStuff = x => x + 1

// doStuff2 :: Number -> Number
const doStuff2 = x => x * 4

const { tagBy, bimap, unwrap } = Either

// doStuff3 :: Number -> Number
const doStuff3 = pipe ([
   tagBy (x => x > 3),
   bimap (doStuff) (doStuff2), // <-- here's the decision!
   unwrap
])

const output1 = doStuff3 (2)
const output2 = doStuff3 (30)

console.log ('output1: ', output1)
console.log ('output2: ', output2)
```

Comment: Lately I tend to be as explicit as possible with conditions by simply wrapping them in functions: `const _let = f => f(); _let((x = someParentScopeVar) => {if (x) return doStuff(x); else return doOtherStuff(x)})`. With abusing default params this way the data flow is explicit. Besides, if instead of `someParentScopeVar` you pass an extensive expression whose result is used several times, you obtain a kind of `let` binding.

Comment: @reify Is this comment in the right place? Maybe you wanted to add this info to OP's question :O

Comment: @reify comment is a little off-topic for this post, but I also think it's a good use of default arguments. I suggest `bind`, `where`, or `assign` as alternative names for `_let`.

Comment: @reify Now I'm questioning whether this should be built-in to the `loop`/`recur` I often write. Starting to feel a lot like Racket's [named-let](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/let.html) and that's a really good thing :D

Comment: @user633183 Thanks! I'm trying to divulge FP, and challenge myself :D

Comment: @user633183 I wrote that comment because I think the basic `Either` type is mainly used because of its monad constraint, where `left` indicates error, not to encode conditional branches. Anyway, thanks for the racket link. I'll look into it.

Comment: @reify Not really. `Either` may be used to leave from a Kleisli composition at certain point outputting `Left`, and continue with `Right`.

Comment: Correct, using `Either` to signal errors is just _one_ possible (but popular) use case.

Comment: @user633183 Yup.

Comment: @user633183 Also, probably an actual case wouldn't involve extracting `Either`'s value as in my sample. The entire composition would be about transforming from/to`Either` and other data types... In a very simple case like OP's, it might look as an overkill, but I supose that the OP and future readers might take the hint to produce more complex solutions using `Either`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you dont want to declare *foo* outside, why you do not simply this way:

```
if(condition) {
  const foo = 1
  do_stuff()
  do_third_stuff(foo)
} else {
  const foo = 0
  do_other_stuff()
  do_third_stuff(foo)
}
```

Comment: Especially if `do_third_stuff()` is more than a one liner, this violates DRY and can lead to hard to maintain code, which in turn leads to a high probablility of bugs when introducing changes (e.g. changing the `if` but forgetting to also change the `else`)